# Trying to create a class that contains objects from another class

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I have created a class called Album, which is this one:

```
public class Album {

    private String Titulo;
    private int temas;
    private int ano;

    public Album(String Titulo2, int temas2, int ano2) {
        this.Titulo = Titulo2;
        this.temas = temas2;
        this.ano = ano2;
    }

    public Album(String Titulo2, int temas2) {
        this.Titulo = Titulo2;
        this.temas = temas2;
    }

    public int getAno() {
        return this.ano;
    }

    public int getTemas() {
        return this.temas;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return this.Titulo;
    }

    public void setAno(int ano) {
        this.ano = ano;
    }

    public boolean foiEditadoNesteSeculo() {
        if (this.ano > 2000) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void adicionaTemasBonus(int x) {
        this.temas += x;
    }

    public void mostraAlbum() {
        System.out.println(this.Titulo + " (editado em " + this.ano + "; tem " + this.temas + " temas)");
    }
}
```

It works fine. The problem is that the teacher asked me to create a new class called `Band` and it has to have an array of Albums. The Band object should be declared with an int that represents the limit of the number of albums (the length of the array). I already have some idea on how to work with arrays, but I have no idea on how to create a type of array that contains objects from another class, and after how to use the attributes of the objects to return something. I think I can figure out the rest after I'm able to properly create the class, though.

Apologies, as it has been described in Portuguese and I don't have much experience in translating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion this would be easier to manage with a `List` so you can add as many `Albums` as you want at any time, however, since the problem statement required `Array` I made an example of a `Band` class.

I also included `main` method to test the program at the bottom of the `Band` class:

```
public class Band {
    private int totalAlbums;
    private Album[] albums;
    private int currentNumberOfAlbums;

    public Band(int totalAlbums) {
        this.totalAlbums = totalAlbums;
        this.albums = new Album[totalAlbums];
        this.currentNumberOfAlbums = 0;
    }

    public Band(Album[] albums) {
       this.totalAlbums = albums.length;
       this.albums = albums;
       this.currentNumberOfAlbums = this.totalAlbums;
    }

    public void addNewAlbum(String titulo, int temas, int ano) {
        if (this.currentNumberOfAlbums == totalAlbums) {
            System.out.println("Warning: Cannot add any more albums, limit reached.");
            return;
        }
        this.albums[this.currentNumberOfAlbums++] = new Album(titulo, temas, ano);

    }

   public void printAlbums() {
       for (Album a : this.albums) {
           a.mostraAlbum();
       }
   }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Band b = new Band(3);
        b.addNewAlbum("The First", 4, 2001);
        b.addNewAlbum("The Second", 98, 2055);
        b.addNewAlbum("The Finale", 12, 2011);
        b.addNewAlbum("The Extra", 12, 2111);

        b.printAlbums();
    }
}
```

There are a few things to look for in this code.

First, to address your direct question, you can simply use a custom class as an array like any other class/primitive with `Album[]`.

Secondly, you will require a `Band` constructor that instantiates the array of `Album` based on an integer passed to it, so you know how many albums are the limit.  You can see this with the `this.albums = new Album[totalAlbums];` line.

Next, you need a way to add a new `Album` *into* the array of `Album[]`.  This can be done a few different ways, but the way I chose was to create a method `addNewAlbum(String, int, int)` to do it for this example which will also increase `currentNumberOfAlbums` by `1` every time a new album is added.  This is useful so you know when an `Album` is attempted to be added even though the `totalAlbums` are already full!  This will prevent an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in your code if `addNewAlbum` is called too many time.

Lastly, in `addNewAlbum` you need to call your `Album` constructor with `new Album(titulo, temas, ano)`.

In my example `main`, a `Band` with limit of `3` albums is created, and `4` albums are attempted to be added into it, with the first 3 adding successfully, and the 4th not being added, but instead printing a warning for being outside the limit.

I also added a `printAlbums()` method which will use your `mostraAlbum()` to print each `Album` in the `albums` array.

**Output:**

```
Warning: Cannot add any more albums, limit reached.
The First (editado em 2001; tem 4 temas)
The Second (editado em 2055; tem 98 temas)
The Finale (editado em 2011; tem 12 temas)
```

**EDIT:**

I added the `Band(Album[] albums)` constructor, you can call this with:

```
Album[] albums = new Album[3];
//Add your albums into this variable
Band b = new Band(albums);
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you! I just forgot that the exercise asks for it to be possible to create a band based on an already created array of albums (and after add albums like you did). This is the only part I'm struggling into right now. You really helped me, though.

Comment: @Carras I added the extra constructor for what you just mentioned and an `EDIT` for how you call it.

Comment: what if I wanted to write a method, let's say it's called ```albumWithMostTemas()```, and I want to loop inside of the Band and return the Album inside the Band that has the most temas (as in Album Class)? @Nexevis

Comment: @Carras Look at my `printAlbums()` method, but instead of printing with `a.mostraAlbum()`, inside of the loop you can use something like `if (a.getTemas() > currentMax) { } ` where you keep track of `currentMax` as an `int`, and overwrite it inside the `if` it is true based on the current `Album` each loop and keep track of the `Album` associated with it.  After the loop is done, return the `Album` that remained.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Band {
    private Album[] albums;
    private numberOfAlbums;
    //...

    // create an empty constructor
    Band(){
        albums = new Album[];
        numberOfAlbums = 0;
    }
    // constructor that receives the albums
    Band(Album[] albums){
        this.albums = albums;
        this.numberOfAlbums = albums.length;
    }

    // constructor that receives the number of albums
    Band(int numOfAlbums){
        this.numberOfAlbums = numOfAlbums;
        this.albums = new Album[numOfAlbums];
    }

    // add getters and setters
    // example of adding a new album
    public void addNewAlbum(Album album){
        if(this.numOfAlbums == this.albums.length){
            // you need to create a new array with a bigger size, copy the existing data and insert the album
            // or whatever you'd like
        } else {
             this.albums[this.numOfAlbums] = album;
             // increment the numOfAlbums
             this.numOfAlbums++;
        }
    }
}

private class Album {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add [] to define that the field is an array.

```
public class Band {
    private int totalAlbums;
    private Album[] albums;
    //...
}

private class Album {
    //...
}
```

Comment: okay, but how am I supposed to fill this array with albums? I really don't understand, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example helps you.

```
    private Album[] albums; // array of album
    private int albumLimit; // limit for album

    public Band(int albumLimit) {
        this.albumLimit = albumLimit; // initialize limit
        this.albums = new Album[albumLimit]; // set limit of album array
    }

    // here it creates a new Album every time the loop runs
    // you can fill the array in other ways too
    public void fillAlbum() {
        for (int i = 0; i < albumLimit; i++) {
            String name = "name_" + i;
            int team = i;

            albums[i] = new Album(name, team);
        }
    }

    public void printAlbum() {
        for (int i = 0; i < albumLimit; i++) {
            System.out.println("Name :" + albums[i].getTitulo());
            System.out.println("Team :" + albums[i].getTemas());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```